# Validate 3 Alpha- 3 Numeric- 1Alpha

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I require some assistance in some sort of Validation within Excel. Im using office 2013.

The users are capturing the below string as 3 Alpha, 3-Numeric, 1 Alpha

```
BFE234G
DFR321F
DFE234F
RED1234
RED123F
```

I want to validation either in VBA or formula to show me all the error in capturing. Above error `(RED1234)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this function to vba module....

```
Function IsValid(ByVal strVal As String) As Boolean
    Dim blnValid As Boolean

    If Len(strVal) <> 7 Then
        IsValid = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    If IsNumeric(Mid(strVal, 4, 3)) = False Then
        IsValid = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Left(strVal, 3) Like WorksheetFunction.Rept("[a-zA-Z]", 3) = False Then
        IsValid = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Right(strVal, 1) Like WorksheetFunction.Rept("[a-zA-Z]", 1) = False Then
        IsValid = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    IsValid = True
End Function
```

Then use function in cell "=IsValid(B1)" etc.....

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple function such as:

```
Function IsValid(ByVal strVal As String) As Boolean
   IsValid = (strVal Like "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z]")
End Function
```

**EDIT** as per comment from @Slai

```
Function IsValid(ByVal strVal As String) As Boolean
   IsValid = (strVal Like "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]###[a-zA-Z]")
End Function
```

This will allow case mixing. If you want to ensure the letters are uppercase, change the `[a-zA-Z]` elements to `[A-Z]`

Comment: `#` is short for `[0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

Excel formula alternative in case the user doesn't enable macros:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((FIND(MID(A1,ROW(1:8),1),"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")>10)*10^ROW(1:8))=10001110
```

The above will return `TRUE` if there are any digits at the end, and `#VALUE!` error for any characters not found in the string, so you can either handle that with Data Validation or `IFERROR` and `LEN` functions:

```
=(LEN(A1)=7)*IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT((FIND(MID(A1,ROW(1:8),1), 
                     "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")>10)*10^ROW(1:8)),)=10001110
```